# ESTA for Outward & Return transit. UK-USA-Costa Rica

Tags: transit, esta

We are travelling from UK to Costa Rica via USA. We have ESTA transit visas for the outward transit. Do we need to apply again when in Costa Rica for ESTA in order to complete transit on return leg to UK via JFK

Comment: ESTAs are normally valid for 2 years. Will your ESTA expire while you're in Costa Rica?

Answer (score 3):

An ESTA is not granted for a specific trip, but is instead valid for 2 years from the date that it's issue.  Within that 2 years you are able to enter the US multiple times, with each visit falling under the provisions of the US Visa Waiver Program (VWP).

There is no need to obtain a new ESTA for your return trip unless your original one expires before you enter the US for the return trip, if you obtain a new passport, or if any of the details provided during the ESTA application change (eg, citizenship, criminal record, etc)